# How to show more than one Membership Role for each user on a GridView as CheckBox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, asp.net-membership

I am implementing Membership for username and role creation in my web application.  My manager 
wants to show username as one column of a GridView, beneath which the username should be displayed (again), and Roles should be placed as other column names of the grid.  The roles assigned to each user should be present in checkbox form, with roles assigned in that column as checked and vice-versa.

Here is my code to retrieve Username and Role from Membership database:

```
var roles = from MembershipUser u in Membership.GetAllUsers()
                select new
                {
                    User = u.UserName,
                    Role = Roles.GetRolesForUser(u.UserName).FirstOrDefault()
                };
```

Based on this query, I need to get the above explained GridView.  Can someone show me how to do that?

Comment: It might be a good idea to show a mock-up of what you're wanting.  It's hard to understand the structure of this grid / interface the way you've descrived it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var roles = from MembershipUser u in Membership.GetAllUsers()
                select new { User = u.UserName, 
                    Role = string.Join(",", Roles.GetRolesForUser(u.UserName))
```

***Update:***

ASPX:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
        onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Username">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("col0") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Role(Admin)">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAdmin" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("col1") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Role(User)">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkUser" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("col2") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindGridviewData();
}
protected void BindGridviewData()
{  
    DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
    dTable.Columns.Add("col0", typeof(string));
    dTable.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(bool));
    dTable.Columns.Add("col2", typeof(bool));
    foreach (MembershipUser u in Membership.GetAllUsers())
    {
        DataRow dRow = dTable.NewRow();
        dRow[0] = u.UserName;

        string[] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(u.UserName);
        dRow[1] = roles.Contains("Admin") ? true : false;
        dRow[2] = roles.Contains("User") ? true : false;
        dTable.Rows.Add(dRow);
    }
    GridView1.DataSource = dTable;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: I think this gets the OP a little closer to what they're going for.  They will need to do some processing if they want that series of checkboxes for what roles a user has or doesn't have.

Comment: @SamieyMehdi Thank u very much sir.this is what i wanted.

Comment: @SamieyMehdi Sir i want to add an option to select the row of the grid and delete it with the button outside it...How to do it..